# How to find the scene position of an object, within a rotating parent object

Tags: three.js

Within my THREE scene i have an Object that rotates. The child object is positioned at (92,92,92) within the rotating Object, so it orbits the centre position (0,0,0) is a spherical path with my mouse movement. How can i find the global position of the child object in respect to the scene as it rotates.  I'm fairly new to THREE.js and thankful for any support in advance.

My code:

```
      ObjectParent = new THREE.Object3D();
      scene.add( ObjectParent );

      ObjectChild = new THREE.Object3D();
      ObjectParent.add( ObjectChild );

      ObjectChild.position.set(92,92,92);
```

Render:

```
     ObjectParent.rotation.y -= (target.y + ObjectParent.rotation.y) * 0.08;    
     ObjectParent.rotation.x += (target.x - ObjectParent.rotation.x) * 0.07;

     ObjectParent.updateMatrixWorld();
     scene.updateMatrixWorld();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you usually do not need to call

```
ObjectParent.updateMatrixWorld();
scene.updateMatrixWorld();
```

inside your render loop. The renderer will do that for you.

To find the world position of a `child` object, you can use this pattern:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
...
vector.setFromMatrixPosition( child.matrixWorld );
```

The renderer should have previously updated the scene matrices for you. If you have changed a parent's position since the last rendering, you will have to first call

```
parent.updateMatrixWorld();
```

to update the relevant matrices.

It is a good idea to look at the three.js source code so you understand what these functions do.

three.js r.67

Comment: I perfectly understand the part related to the child's world position but not sure about the part for .updateMatrixWorld() and I read the source... when at the end you write "parent.updateMatrixWorld();" the difference with ObjectParent is that your lowercase parent is not child of the scene? I would like to understand a little bit more about updating matrices because I'm asking myself if any kind of missing matrix update can be connected to my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970246/problems-in-finding-univocal-coordinates-from-inside-a-sphere ... thanks a lot!