# Problems in finding univocal coordinates from inside a sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working with Three.js [r78] and I'm pretty a noob both on this and JavaScript in general

I finally managed to broadcast a ray from a perspective cam in the centre of a sphere with radius equal to 500 and the results for the intersections when I checked with the browser were good but not really satisfactory. I would need to exactly individuate the coordinates of a point [cartesian or spherical doesn't matter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiHWw.jpg) together with lat e lon of the same point. When I select a specific point I get different values for its cartesian coordinates. Sometimes these values are not that distant, sometimes quite different. There are problems with the zoom [mousewheel] but unfortunately also without changing it, like in the example below where I added a white marker to show the point apparently selected. The real clicked one is the one inside the red circle

[image: intersection with marker]

Here the same point is seen from different viewports but with same zoom. I would expect these two attempts to give the same values [circa, of course]. On the other side I checked that the distance from camera to the intersection point is always 500-, so the collision point seems to be perfectly calculated

My two questions and then the essential code [the rest comes from [Valiant360](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDUnT.jpg)]:

- the same physical point [mouse click in the red circle] calculated with two different coordinates is a bug of this Three.js release or am I forgetting something/doing some mistakes? in other words I would like to get the same coordinates for the same physical clicked point, indipendently from the viewport
- if it is my fault what to do to fix it and possibly having the same values also changing the zoom

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help, 
Antonino

---

```
    onMouseDown: function(a) 
    {
    [...]

    // retrieving normalized coordinates
    var mouse_2D_vector = new THREE.Vector2( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
                                    -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1);        

    this._raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse_2D_vector, this._camera);

    var intersections = this._raycaster.intersectObjects( [this._mesh], true );
    intersection = ( intersections.length ) > 0 ? intersections[ 0 ] : null;

    if (intersections.length>0)
    {
        intersections[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

        console.log("Intersected object.x:", intersections[ 0 ].point.x);
        console.log("Intersected object.y:", intersections[ 0 ].point.y);
        console.log("Intersected object.z:", intersections[ 0 ].point.z);
    }

    console.log('intersections.length: ' + intersections.length);       

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with raycasting is:

If the scene is not EXACTLY window.innerWidth x window.innerHeight then the "mouse click" location on the screen can be miscalculated due to the fact that you are scaling incorrectly. This is not a bug with Three.js, it's just an issue with people reusing the same code over and over again for raycasting without realizing that the scale needs to be adjusted.

You could either hard code the width and height to replace window.innerwidth/height

or use JQuery $elements

Comment: Dear Rush2112 when I started analyzing the problem I thought about a matrix update problem and/or a render problem. I thought it was the first - so my fault - because as I told you I'm not yet that much into JS, it could have been inexperience. But the problem showed also in the 1st viewport, thus I understood. Then I fixed it before your answer using another beautiful example that was exactly like mine with the difference that you told. Your answer is EXACTLY the fix I applied and for the time spent in analyzing my question you absolutely deserve the points for the right answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It was hard to identify the specific question you're asking. Can you summarize in **bold** what your question is?

But I think that your question is basically, why is it reading out anything other than 500 as the distance to the intersection.

The reason for that, is that you're dealing with a generated geometry, so the shape is not actually round. If it were perfectly round, then of course the distance from center to the outside would be 500, but because our geometry needs to have specific faces in order to be displayed, it generates triangles between points like so:

[image]

In the center of each of those triangles, the distance from the center will be something close to, but not equal to 500. If you look for the distance exactly at one of the intersections, then it will read out 500 exactly, but the closer you get to the center of a triangle, the shorter the distance will become. And this effect is magnified the simpler your shape is.

Again, I think this is what you're asking. But update your question if I missed something, because it is not clear from your post.

Comment: hello @OtterFamily and thanks for your answer! My question is: when I cast a ray from the sphere centre to the mouse position [clicking inside the red circle of the pictures above] with the code shown I get another point on the renderer, both visually [see the white marker above] and mathematically. Is it a bug from three.js or I'm doing something wrong to get the coordinates of the point clicked by the mouse? thanks again, much appreciated